# No SIM card detected -- factory reseted and now it works. What now?

Tags: applications, backup, sim-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy S 5 rooted and flashed CyanogenMod 12.1 on it (Android 5.1.1). Everything always have worked fine.

Earlier this week, I have installed a new app in my phone. Although I cannot 100% blame the app, after a reboot having this app installed, the phone could not recognize the SIM card anymore. It always was showing me the message `No SIM card detected`. Even after I uninstalled the app, rebooted, removed SIM card, re-rebooted, re-inserted the SIM card, re-re-rebooted, wiped Dalvik, wiped cache, upgraded the ROM, the problem persisted.

I finally decided to make a full ROM backup and then a factory reset.

The SIM card is now correctly recognized, as before.

Now what should I do? Re-install every app I had before and re-configure each of them one by one? Restore the backup with chance that the SIM card will not be recognized again? And if it won't, how can I solve this problem without the need of a full factory reset and re-installation/configuration of all my apps?

What are the steps to go through this situation?

Comment: I think app installations has nothing to do with the sim card detection. [Low level access to the SIM card is not available to third-party apps. The OS handles all communications with the SIM card including access to personal information (contacts) on the SIM card memory.](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/overview/app-security.html#sim-card-access).

Comment: I agree with you, I also don't think there would be any security breach that the app could have used with the intention of not letting me make calls anymore... Anyway, I have restored the backup and the problem was "restored" with it, implying there's nothing wrong with the hardware.

Comment: How exactly are you restoring backups into your device? using `adb` commands or some other tool?

Comment: @Lucky I have made the backup just with the phone, in recovery mode using TeamView Recovery. I restored it using the same way.

Comment: Use [Nandroid Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore&hl=en) or [TWRP Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flaki.twrpexplorer&hl=en) or [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) to restore *strictly* the apps and their data. Nothing more nothing less. You would  be restoring many things other than apps if the restore is done using a Recovery.

Comment: @Firelord Great I'll try. I'm confident on that, it makes sense. Would restoring just apps and data be restoring system settings as well? Like my face model used on face unlock, led notification colors etc.? Even if it wouldn't I can live with that, but it would be nice if I wouldn't need to make these settings as well. I'll try that and post back here soon.

Comment: The system apps are technically apps too and their data is stored under the same directory where other third-party apps keep their data. But it is up to you whether you want to restore the system apps or not. I suggest you do not at first place so that you can figure out what's causing that SIM issue. Also note that most of the settings are stored in the app Settings Storage (not Settings).

Comment: I restored data *only* ontop of a factory reseted ROM. Still no SIM card detected.

Comment: Could one of the system apps got corrupted somehow? Here's an idea: I'll make a full backup of a factory reseted system, restore data only from the the faulty backup, and then restore data only from the wipe backup on the faulty one. This would, in theory, overwrite only the system default applications and replace them with a working copy. Assuming of course the problem is occurring on a system app, and not because of some third-party app.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problema, but with TWRP.

Comment: I had to keep the backup that worked after a factory reset and have a fresh start with it -- it means I had to reinstall and configure every single app I previously had. I still can't explain what happened, and it never happened again.